# Fabric (Crashlytics): Newest build not visible in 'Latest release' section

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

After the new version (3.5.9) of the app has been in production for couple of days, it is visible in Crashlytics secion of Fabric:

[image]

but is not in 'Latest Release':

[image]

What's interesting, on the top there is an old version of the app that isn't used that much now.

What could be the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: Can you go to the manual URL for the build you are interested in and take a screenshot of that page? I'm interested to see what it looks like. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've reached out to Fabric support and got an answer:

> The Latest Releases page shows all builds that have been used by at
>   least 10% of your Daily Active Users (DAU) on any single day in the
>   past 30 days or at least 4% of DAU on the current day. What's likely
>   happening is that 3.5.9 isn't hitting the criteria just yet.
>
> As a workaround, if you manually add the version and build to the URL
>   i.e. ".../dashboard/latest_release/launch_status?build=3.5.9" you can
>   see the latest release information for that build.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you, can you see this

[image: fabric]