# Fabric is not showing our latest release in the dashboard

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

In the "Latest Release" section, our release 2.1.6 is visible, but we are currently on 2.2.3 version.

That's weird because 2.1.6 release was released a long time ago..

Crashlytics "All versions":

[image]

Why do I see multiple builds here? How can I select build 2.2.4.1 without version code?

I've checked this post : [Fabric (Crashlytics): Newest build not visible in 'Latest release' section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797018/fabric-crashlytics-newest-build-not-visible-in-latest-release-section)

and tried to manually add version name ".../dashboard/latest_release/launch_status?build=2.2.3" but it says 0 users, 0 sessions.. and even weirdest thing is, if I add 2.1.6 that is visible in "Latest release" section, I also get 0 users, 0 sessions..

Any ideas what could go wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fabric (Crashlytics): Newest build not visible in 'Latest release' section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797018/fabric-crashlytics-newest-build-not-visible-in-latest-release-section)

Comment: I referred to that post since the answer from that post is not working for me

Comment: Thanks! Is this for an iOS or Android app? Usually this means that you've had over 200 builds since the build you are trying to track. To get access to the build of interest, you'll need to use the manual URL or hide other builds in your settings.